# How do I create a php function or any script/jquery Javascript that will allow me to take the values associated with a checkbox and add them?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

// The user can only select the seat number checkbox before selecting econ,goodseat or firstclass, if the user clicks on one of the goodseat/econ/firstclass checkboxes without selecting the seat number checkbox a messagepopup or validation should be present indicating that the seat number checkbox must be selected first.

Also the price value is determined by how many seats are checked. for example lets say the price of the ticket is $120, and he selects seat number two's checkbox and seat number one's checkbox, then the total should be $240 and so on. goodseat, econ, and firstclass checkboxes do not increase the price. They are only there for the sake of seating arrangment. In order for the user to click on the add_submit button, atleast one checkbox must be selected. How do I create this? Someone please help me. And what must i type in my session script so that once the selections have been made and he clicks add_submit button the next page will remember the total and travel details.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Gtd.png)

```
Here is my php page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>

td{

    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
p{
font-size: 16px;

}
</style>
<body>
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<?php

       $str = $_GET['Confirm'];
       $array = (explode(",",$str)); 
      ?>


<h1>Booking Details</h1>

travel Details:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> key id
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $array[0] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        destination</td>
        <td> <?php echo $array[1] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        arrival</td>
        <td> <?php echo $array[2] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Price</td>
        <td> $<?php echo $array[3] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["key_id"] = $array[0];
$_SESSION["destination"] = $array[1];
$_SESSION["arrival"] = $array[2];
$_SESSION["price"] = $array[3];
echo "Session variables for this booking have been set.";
?>
<form action="Yourbookings.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Seat #</td>
    <td>econ </td>
    <td>firstclass</td>
    <td>goodseat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 1 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="seat1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="econ" value="econ"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="firstclass" value="firstclass"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="goodseat" value="goodseat"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 2 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="seat1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="econ" value="econ"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="firstclass" value="firstclass"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="goodseat" value="goodseat"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Seat 3 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="seat1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="econ" value="econ"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="firstclass" value="firstclass"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="goodseat" value="goodseat"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Seat 4 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="seat1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="econ" value="econ"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="firstclass" value="firstclass"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="goodseat" value="goodseat"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Seat 5 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="seat1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="econ" value="econ"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="firstclass" value="firstclass"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="goodseat" value="goodseat"> </td>
</tr>


</table>

<p>Total = $</p>
// what code do I create to so that it adds the ticket prices based on how many seats are selected.
<?php
$_SESSION["price"] = $array[3];


?>



<input type="submit" name="Add booking" value="Add_booking">
</form>



<table>
<td>
<form action="add_booking.php" method="get">

</td>
</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I am understanding what you are saying and I think you will want to do this in javascript, also with radio buttons *(I think)*, a hidden price field, and a `readonly` field:

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/h6aawjf0/

**Scripts:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on('click','.clearit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked',false);
        $('input[name=total]').val('0');
    });

    $(this).on('change','input[type=radio]',function() {
        var radioBtns   =   $('input[type=radio]');
        var price       =   $('input[name=price]').val();
        var sum         =   0;

        $.each(radioBtns,function(k,v) {
            if($(v).is(":checked"))
                sum +=  1;
        });
        $('input[name=total]').val((sum*price));
    });
});
</script>

<form action="Yourbookings.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="120" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Seat #</td>
            <td>econ </td>
            <td>firstclass</td>
            <td>goodseat</td>
        </tr>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<5;$i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Seat <?php echo $i; ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="econ"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="firstclass"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="goodseat"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
        <input type="text" name="total" readonly value="0" />
    <input type="submit" name="Add booking" value="Add_booking">
    <input type="submit" class="clearit" value="CLEAR">
</form>
```

The output after selection and submission would be something like:

```
Array (
        [price] => 120
        [1] => econ
        [2] => firstclass
        [3] => firstclass
        [4] => econ
        [total] => 480
        [Add_booking] => Add_booking
    )
```

Comment: close but there must be four checkboxes on each row. One for the seat number and the other three for econ, business , firstclass. You description shows only three. What I want to be able to achieve is having users click on seat number and then if they want they can select any of the three check-boxes. if they dont select any check-boxes and then click on add_button/submit a popup or validation should state they they must atleast select one seat number. In addition if a user were to click on a checkbox without selecting a seatnumber checkbox a popup or validation should be brought up.

Comment: So each seat can have mulitple options? Like seat1 can be `econ`, `firstclass`, and `goodseat` all at the same time?

Comment: correct i know it doesnt make sense because of the values, maybe I should have changed them to wheelchair, extra drinks, extra food etc Each seat can have multiple values

Comment: How total amount must only add values associated with the checkbox that corresponds with the seatnumber. If a user was to select a checkbox for special diet or econ or firstclass that wouldnt affect the total costs. so if a user were to select two seats, seatnumber 1 and seat number 2 and the price for a single ticket is $100 then the total would be 200. how can I then create a session that would save these flight details.

Comment: You would just submit the form or you would have to do AJAX to update the session.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about because I am a beginner.

Comment: Well if the form was correct, the user could click a "total" button and it would submit the for but only as an update which would save the data from the form to a session. Then you would do a final submission to save the booking. The ajax is too much to go into. I have already done  a lot of script for this.